# How to view force installation of package even if trigger fails?

Tags: apt, package-management, bootloader

Is there a way to view the commands that would be run as part of installing a package and to say "proceed with installing the package, even if this particular command/trigger fails"?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and recently did an `apt-get upgrade`. Just about the only strange thing I've done on this box is switch the bootloader from GRUB to LILO. LILO's not actively developed anymore, but it seems to work well on my laptop.

When attempting to upgrade `initramfs-tools`, some of the post-installation steps have failed, causing all of the changes to be backed out.

Based on reading the error output, I am guessing that this issue could be resolved by spot-checking `/etc/lilo.conf` to see if it looks okay and then just re-running `lilo` after the package has been updated.

Here's the command and full output.

```
[~] > sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
initramfs-tools is already the newest version (0.130ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Fatal: open /dev/disk/by-id/: Is a directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Exit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this *particular problem* by uninstalling `lilo`, updating, and then reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get remove lilo -y
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install lilo -y
```

installing `lilo` requires answering some questions about enabling large-memory support &c.

The specific error message probably refers to one of these files in 
`/var/lib/dpkg/*`:

```
$ grep -r '/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/runlilo' /var/lib/dpkg/info/
/var/lib/dpkg/info/lilo.list:/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/runlilo
/var/lib/dpkg/info/lilo.conffiles:/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/runlilo
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out which options to pass to `apt-get` to be able to narrow down which specific trigger is responsible ... and I also haven't been able to figure out how to cleanly override triggers in a safe way.